# lex/yacc won't recognize a string (syntax error)

Tags: lex

Hi i'm trying to let lex/yacc split this string

```
table subwayLines:int[3]
```

into tokens of table, subwayLines, int[3] with the [3] optional(i.e. int or int[3])

everything is fine until i try to recognize the "int",
so this is what i did in lex

```
[A-Za-z0-9\[\]]+    { /* column property*/ 
                   yylval.sval = (char *)strdup(yytext);
           char* temp=yylval.sval;
            return STRING;
                 }
```

i know the problem is in

```
[A-Za-z0-9\[\]]+
```

because when i changed it to

```
[A-Za-z]+("[")?+[0-9]+("]")?+(",")?
```

it works except I still can't go without the "[" or "]", for example, if i wrote this in my string:

```
table subwayLines:int
```

then it gives me a syntax error
so does anyone knows how to do change it? thanks

Comment: Is there a reason to recognize `int[3]` as a string token, rather than to return that as four tokens and parse the syntax? What if there is whitespace (is that allowed?) I.e. `int [ 3 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `[3]` optional, this will not work:

```
[A-Za-z]+("[")?+[0-9]+("]")?+(",")?
```

You've made only the square brackets optional, but not the number in between. You need something like

```
[A-Za-z]+("["[0-9]+"]")?
```

I.e. the entire square-bracketed part is optional.

Also the combination `(REGEX)?+` doesn't make much sense (the `?+` part of it). It's equivalent to `(REGEX)*`, since you're effectively saying that `(REGEX)` is optional, one or more times, which is like zero or more.

(Not sure why you have the optional comma in the second example; the first one doesn't recognize a comma and it's not shown in your example input.)